# Unable to get a SQL-Server connection

Tags: java, sql-server

Im having difficulties trying to get a connection to my sqlserver database.
The database im using is SQL-Server 2008.
The driver im using is the one i got here: [Microsoft download page](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21599)

I use the following code:

```
public static final String URL_FORMAT = "jdbc:sqlserver://%s:%s;DatabaseName=%s";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        String connectionURL = String.format(URL_FORMAT, "10.31.3.3", 1433, "EPowerTest");
        System.out.println("connecting to: "+connectionURL);
        
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "sa", "*************");
        if (connection == null) {
            System.out.println("no connection was established");
        } else {
            System.out.println("succesfully connected");
        }
    }
```

Now this piece of code runs on my developers machine, im getting the following results:

> connecting to: jdbc:sqlserver://***.***.***.***:1433;DatabaseName=******
>
> succesfully connected

But when i run this piece of code on my developers machine it prints the follwing:

> connecting to: jdbc:sqlserver://10.31.3.3:1433;DatabaseName=*******

and the second line never gets printed, because it seems DriverManager.getConnection does not return. This is not a firewall issue, since all three terminals (db server, developers machine and the test machine) are all on the same network. Why is my method not returning? am i missing some important SQLServer files?

Hope anyone here can help me with this annoying problem!

Comment: There might be a timeout, how long did you wait for the call to return?

Comment: about 10 minutes before i gave up, this is definitly not a timeout!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the JVM in the machine that the connections hangs is the version [1.6.0_29](http://dertompson.com/2011/11/29/jdbc-connection-to-sql-server-2008-hangs-because-of-jdk-1-6-u29/). If it is, upgrade to a newer Java.

Here is [another link](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/696635/jdbc-connection-hangs-since-security-update-kb2539636) explaining the issue.

Comment: Great, that solved my problem Luciano, how did you come to this answer? i did not find any results on google!

Comment: Because it happened to me some time ago. But I just searched for sql server hang connection java (or something like that) and there were results on Google.